# Can i use a centralized external config file for c#?

Tags: app-config, external

I found an article on using external config files [here](http://blog.andreloker.de/post/2008/06/Keep-your-config-clean-with-external-config-files.aspx).  While I was able to extract my config settings, I was unable to put them in a central location.

When i tried to do something like this:

```
  <connectionStrings configSource="C:/dev/Configs/ConnectionStrings.config" />
```

It causes a type initializer exception.  If i put the file in a folder under the bin directory, it's ok.  Problem is, I want to keep the config files central to all apps so i can reuse it in a lot of places.

Is it just not doable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Symbolic Links.  I created a subfolder under each app that symlinked back to the master config folder.  All apps share the same Connection Strings now.